# How do I tell NetBeans where my Tomcat "home" is?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, catalina

Because I do not have admin privileges on my computer, I have installed Tomcat 8.0.33 in my User directory using the Windows installer.  I was then able to add Tomcat to NetBeans 8.1, just fine.  However, when I try to run my web application from NetBeans, I get:

```
NetBeans: Deploying on tomcat80:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
```

... and it never actually deploys my web application.

Notice, it is claiming that `tomcat80:home` is set to the default NetBeans installation folder ... not where I actually installed it.  This is despite the fact that NetBeans displays the proper `Catalina Home` value:

[image]

How do I properly set that `tomcat80:home` value?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Same issue. Tomcat is not in the usual place (per company policy) and I can't point netbeans to the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but still thought of answering this as I ran into this issue today. After lot of research, I found this answer and thought may be useful to someone else too.

The tomcat80:home variable is actually in a file called attributes.xml. In my Ubuntu desktop, it is located in /home/MYUSERNAME/.netbeans/8.2/var

Changing the variable's value to point to new location also didn't help. So, I just took a copy of the attributes.xml and deleted it. Restarted Netbeans and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, delete the following file:

C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\var\attributes.xml

Restart Netbeans